# What courses require multivariable analysis?

Tags: soft-question, education

For which undergraduate and introductory graduate mathematics courses is a rigorous course in multivariable analysis an essential prerequisite?

Comment: Real analysis, complex analysis, *ad infinitum*.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that multivariable analysis is really needed for real analysis or complex analysis.  It's definitely needed for differential geometry, differential topology, and (probably) partial differential equations.

Comment: @JesseMadnick True, but real analysis and complex analysis set the basis for the elements of *ad infinitum*.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar: I'm not sure I know what you mean. At any rate, I can agree that basic real analysis is needed for multivariable analysis, but I don't see how multivariable analysis is needed for most real analysis topics (e.g. measure theory, functional analysis).